# How to reorder Libreoffice Writer sections?

Tags: libreoffice-writer

I have set up a document using document sections and would now like to put one before another.

Is this easy to do? How is it done?

`Insert > Sections...` and `Format > Sections...` seemed like they ought to allow it but seem not to.